# Laravel QR Codes: endroid/QrCode, how to use it?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

I would like to use a QR-Code generator with my Laravel 4.1 application. I am currently choosing between https://github.com/endroid/QrCode and https://github.com/endroid/EndroidQrCodeBundle. To be honest though, neither appear to have any documentation on how to use them.

Can someone describe the first steps, after an successful composer installation, on how to produce QR codes?

Thank you in advance for every step. I know this is kind of a generic question, but I am kind of new to Laravel.

Comment: What in the documentation for endroid is giving you trouble? BTW, bundles are no longer used in Laravel 4.

Comment: I know, I am installing them through composer. To answer your question, everything gives me trouble. For other bundles, I have to write often things into the app/config.php file (aliases or ServiceProvider), and I don't at all how to start on this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an alias or service provider. Just use the example code as a route's return. `Route::get('test', function() { $qrCode = new Endroid\QrCode\QrCode();
$qrCode->setText("Life is too short to be generating QR codes");
$qrCode->setSize(300);
$qrCode->setPadding(10);
return $qrCode->render(); }`

Comment: I have followed the code and the result is a garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this late response but for anyone who is having this challenge, this is fairly simple;

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
class ImageController extends Controller{

    public function _construct(QrCode $qrCode){
        $this->qrCode = $qrCode;
    }

    public function makeQrCode($text){
       return $this->qrCode
       ->setText($text)
       ->setSize(300)
       ->setPadding(10)
       ->setErrorCorrection('high')
       ->setForegroundColor(array('r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0))
       ->setBackgroundColor(array('r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0))
       ->setLabel('My label')
       ->setLabelFontSize(16)
       ->render();
    }
}
```

You route may look like this:

```
Route::get('image/qrcode/{$text}',[
  'uses' => 'ImageController@makeQrCode',
  'as'   => 'qrcode'
]);
```

So later you can do this in your blade:

```
<img src="{!! route('qrcode',['text'=>'Hello world']) !!}" alt="QR Code">
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. If you know, why would you prefer a php (serverside) solution, instead of letting javascript do the qr code generation? Any pro or contra right now in your mind?

Comment: Well, I arrived at your question because I was looking for a package that will be able to generate qrcode so I can store it my database. I prefer to use serverside qrcode generator in my own scenario because my app is an API which must generates a serials of unqiue PIN number s(14 digits) and generate qrcode fo each PIN number. I am using this. https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode

Comment: Bro Its working very well. But i want to generate qrcode for a big string, around 4000 character. in this case this will failed. How can i solve this issue.